# MSBuild Deleting Unnecessary Files

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I use TeamCity to run MSBuild to deploy a .NET website we have. The site uses the Sitecore CMS, which includes three folders, a few hundred files (and mbs) that have to bee in the main website root folder.

Currently, MSBuild deletes the entire web root folder before deploying itself into it. This causes two problems:

1) Our CMS is not accessible during the ~ 2 minutes it takes to deploy
2) The actual deployment takes long because we have to run a batch script to copy all of those files into the web directory after deployment.

Is there a way to have MSBuild not clear the whole root directory before deployment, or have it ignore certain folders? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, although I have [found there is a 'skip'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) setting you can use on MSDeploy to do just this very thing.

Seemingly MSDeploy commands work in MSBuild I am not the much further ahead of you.

I need to delete all except for 2 directories, and copy the rest across. Let me know if you've made progress.